# In JQuery is it possible to skip an optional argument and pass the next ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JQuery is it possible to skip an optional argument and pass the next ones? if yes, how a jquery function determines which value is for which parameter?

An example:

```
//
// function signature is
// jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
//
// function is called as
//
$.get('ajax/test.html', function (data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

In call to $.get() after the url the [, data] is skipped and next the success callback is passed.

Comment: Do you have an example of a method you want to do this on?

Comment: Off topic, but i know that its always good to put optional parameter as the last parameter

Comment: jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )

$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});

in call to $.get() after the url the [, data] is skipped and next the success callback is passed

Comment: @csstd: jQuery should automatically determine which parameter it is from the type, but if it can't, that's when you use an object for options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible to *skip* optional arguments, even from the middle. jQuery looks at the type of arguments to determine which is which. Have a look at the signature of [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
.load(url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)])
```

And the following work as expected:

```
.load("test.php")
.load("test.php", {foo: bar})
.load("test.php", {foo: bar}, function(){})
.load("test.php", function(){}) // you skipped the 2nd parameter? no.
```

You'll notice that the three parameters are: `string`, `object` and `function`. Inside the function jQuery can easily check how many arguments were passed and their types. If it notices that the 2nd parameter is a function it will assume that `data` parameter was skipped and act accordingly.

To your surprise, there is another [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function with different signature which does something entirely different:

```
.load(handler(eventObject))
.load([eventData], handler(eventObject))
```

Again, jQuery can determine which method to fire by looking at the arguments.

Comment: I don't get how your answer is _"No"_ since your explanation basically says "yes". I don't get how this _"...will assume that data parameter was skipped and..."_ comes after this _"// you skipped the 2nd parameter? no"_.

Answer (score 1):

Not as you might be used to. Some functions might take an object for options, such as `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'whatever',
    data: {some: 'thing'}
});
```

As opposed to:

```
$.ajax('whatever', {
    data: {some: 'thing'}
});
```

Using the former form would allow you to omit the URL and use the default. (Not the best example, but it's the only one I can think of out of all of jQuery offhand. Do you have a particular case in mind?)

Comment: signature: Query.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] ) 

call: $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) { $('.result').html(data); alert('Load was performed.'); });

 in call to $.get() after the url the [, data] is skipped and next the success callback is passed

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a matter of jQuery, as it has more to do with the functionality of JavaScript itself. The jQuery functions were made utilizing arguments. Arguments that are passed the function have types. We can test what type these arguments are and therefore determine what they are being used for.

```
function foo( show, text ) {

    if ( typeof show === "function" ) show( text );

    else if ( !show ) alert( text );

}
```

We use `typeof` to find the type. If an argument is excluded from the function call, its type is `undefined`. `undefined` is a falsy type. Other falsy types are `0`, `false`, `NaN`, empty string (`""`), and `null`. We can test a variables falsy-ness using the logical NOT operator, `!`.

Moving on, if we know that `show` is a function, we can use it as a function and call it with the argument `text`.

```
foo(function (text) { alert(text); }, "Hello World"); // alerts "Hello World"
```